# Is there any reason to use the Attack command with an insect glaive?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In Monster Hunter World, when you mount a monster, you have 3 main options; Attack, Brace and Move. My understanding of these three are as follows:

- Attack stabs the monster with a knife, doing *very minimal damage* (1 damage per hit!).
- Brace prevents your stamina from depleting whilst they try to shake you off.
- Move allows you to move between the head, body and tail of the monster in order to avoid their attacks against you (i.e trying to bite you whilst you are on it's back or tail). With the insect glaive (and perhaps other weapons - untested), **this deals a considerable amount more damage than simply attacking**.

I can access the toppling special move using either Attack or Move, so I don't believe the Attack command is necessary for that.

Why would anyone use the Attack option whilst mounting? Is there an advantage to using it?

Comment: Might want to edit the question to actually mention mounting

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, only the Insect Glaive can deal damage by moving to a different part of the monster. Every other weapon will just reposition and deal no damage in the process. So for 13 weapons out of 14, attacking by moving simply isn't an option, and the carving knife is the only way to topple the monster.

Secondly, moving drains a considerable amount of stamina, while attacking does not. For monsters which require more hits to fall over, you might run out of stamina before managing to topple the monster if you're only relying on the damage dealt while moving.

Thirdly, you won't be able to focus your damage on one part of the monster. If you're aiming to break one specific body part, you might want to climb on it and attack with the carving knife to be sure you won't waste any damage on other body parts, especially with the finisher.

Comment: The stamina drain on moving is almost negligible. So no other reasons? I would guess this means that if you use the insect glaive then the only time you should be using the carving knife is if you are about to run out of stamina.

Comment: I wouldn't call the stamina drain negligible given that I've seen an Insect Glaive user fail to mount a Rathalos from full stamina just from moving back and forth the entire time.

Comment: As an IG main, especially in harder fights the stamina burn from constantly repositioning is not worth the risk of failing a mount for a little more damage. It's much better to just move one or twice and topple the monster so you and/or your pals can get their hits in.